# how to wildcard filter a sharepoint list on specific multiple fields

Tags: sharepoint-2010, filter, field, foundation

I'm looking for a answer on the question on how to filter a list on multiple fields.
I got a little part of the problem solved, but the problem is I can use it only on one field.

```
if(sQuery1!=""){
    url=url + "FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=" + sQuery
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}
```

this is a small part of me code. I'm using the filtername and filter multivalue to solve me problem, but the problem now is that I can only use it once. I have tried `filtername1` and `filtermultivalue1` but it doesn't seem to work.
Also I have been looking on internet for something that might solve me problem, but couldn't find a thing. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

use * after filtermultivalue:

`if(sQuery1!=""){
    url=url + "FilterName=Title&FilterMultiValue=*" + sQuery +"*"
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}`